# Access rows only belonging to user with userId defined in Jwt token Spring Boot

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-security

I am generating the Jwt token in this way.

```
public String generateToken(String email,long id) {
    Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
    claims.put("userId",id);
    return doGenerateToken(claims, email);
}

private String doGenerateToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {

    return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + Long.parseLong(tokenValidity))).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret).compact();
}
```

The problem I am facing right now is any request with a valid jwt token can access whole data. The goal is to only let data created by same user be fetched.

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

    httpSecurity.cors().and().csrf().disable().headers().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/users/register","/api/users/login","/api/users/token-validate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("**/save").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("**/edit").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("**/delete").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
```

Only messages belonging to the user should be retrievable. Sorry for the bad English.

```
@GetMapping("/get-messages")
public ResponseEntity<GetMessageResponse> getAllMessages(@RequestParam(name = "user-id") long id){
    List<Message> messageList = messageService.findMessagesByUserId(id);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(new GetMessageResponse(MessageList,"Messages Retrieved Successfully", HttpStatus.OK));
}
```

Comment: dont provide the id as an input param, have the id in the jwt as a custom claim. Or fetch data by `subject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using spring you can get the authenticated user using this code:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
Object         principal      = authentication.getPrincipal();
```

This is safer than getting the userId from a request parameter.